# Twitter Bootstrap: How to disable dates before a selected date dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using twitter bootstrap 3.

**This is what i need to implement:**

2 Date pickers. User can select the start and end-date

After selecting the start date i want to disable all the dates preceding it dynamically in the second Date picker.

Many tutorials i searched but they all shows how to disable a particular range of dates.

I hope its clear enough to understand, please guide me if anyone know how to do that.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here I have try to do like this :

[Bootstrap DatePicker](http://www.bootply.com/fpF98qHwIm)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="from_date" placeholder="Select start date" contenteditable="false">
<input type="text" class="to_date" placeholder="Select end date" contenteditable="false">
```

JS:

```
var startDate = new Date('01/01/2012');
var FromEndDate = new Date();
var ToEndDate = new Date();

ToEndDate.setDate(ToEndDate.getDate()+365);

$('.from_date').datepicker({

    weekStart: 1,
    startDate: '01/01/2012',
    endDate: FromEndDate, 
    autoclose: true
})
    .on('changeDate', function(selected){
        startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
        $('.to_date').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
        $('.from_date').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
    }); 
$('.to_date')
    .datepicker({

        weekStart: 1,
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: ToEndDate,
        autoclose: true
    })
    .on('changeDate', function(selected){
        FromEndDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        FromEndDate.setDate(FromEndDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
        $('.from_date').datepicker('setEndDate', FromEndDate);
        $('.to_date').datepicker('setEndDate', FromEndDate);
    });

});
```

I'm using Jquery and the bootstrap datepicker from here : http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

You'll need to include the scripts for jquery and datepicker and the css for the datepicker.

Comment: hi, this is working fine but this is not meeting my needs, in first Datepicker all the dates after today is disabled, but i dont want this....rather i want to disable all the dates before today in first DatePicker...as user can select any date after the current date as well. Its a Travelling blog where journey's start date and end should be entered..

Comment: "After selecting the start date i want to disable all the dates preceding it dynamically in the second Date picker." This statement in your question.

Comment: You can also achieve that. You need to call date changed event for that disable those date.

Comment: exactly, when user selects the start date from first picker resulting the second Date picker disable all the dates before the Start date selected....i think you misinterpret it..

Comment: I think as per your requirements its perfect solution.

Comment: i am not getting the solution....i want something exactly like this [link](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) has in Disabling dates in the past and dependent disabling. section (check-in, check-out). Please guide me accordingly

Comment: Hi, I have makes some changes in solution. please check now on http://www.bootply.com/fpF98qHwIm

Comment: @JaiminSoni : that the solution what i need. Thanks man for post this solution.